# AI movement in a tile based game

Tags: c++, 2d, sfml, grid

I've been tryin to make My AI follow my A* path in grid. the problem is that is goes off course and doesn't move along the path very well. currently got it to move only  left and up.

how I intended it to work is that the character goes to the centre of the Path cells and repeat until the end.

```
void AIEnemy::AutoMotion(  Gridspot& grid)
{
    std::pair<int, int> ecn = getNodePosition();

    std::reverse(grid.Path.begin(), grid.Path.end());
    for (auto path : grid.Path)
    {
            if (path.node.first == ecn.first)
            {
                if (rect.getPosition().y != path.rectCenter.y)
                    rect.move(0, -5);
                break;
            }



            if (path.node.first < ecn.first && path.node.second == ecn.second)
            {

                if  (right != path.rectCenter.x )
                    movetoThe(e_left);
                break;
            }

    }
}
```

Here's how it looks like right now:

[image]

here's how it follows the path:

[image]

my question is how do I make AI character move on its own and alter its direction toward a goal.

Comment: Can you show us an example of a case that causes the AI to go off course? You could include a diagram or animation showing your expected course, and the course the AI takes instead.

Comment: @DMGregory i added eddits so you can a picture of what's going on

Comment: It looks like your AI is successfully following the pink line. What about its movement would you like to change?

Comment: Did you try to debug your path? What does it say? Where do you think the issue lies—is it in the path-finding algorithm, or is it in the moving part of it?

Comment: Is the pink "path" the path you'd like it to follow, or is it the path that is actually computed?

Comment: it's the path I would like it to follow

Comment: I wanted to know if there is 'technique' 2d grid games usually use. also I think the issue lies both with the movement part of it. if i take the take the break; out the loop it will just go straight

Comment: Your AI does not seem to follow exactly the path you've set for it. Make sure that the path your path-finding algorithm is giving you is what you expect, then make sure your AI follows those nodes.

Comment: If it can help, I have made a small project [in the past](https://github.com/vaillancourt/patrol) with AI and path-finding. It's using a grid, without it being really a grid.